# connect from a QTab (in a QTabWidget) back to QMainWindow

Tags: qt, tabwidget, qt-connection

The main part of my application is a Systray-Menu. For maintenance there should be a normal GUI.

My problem is that now I have to create two Signal/Slot-Connections back to the main window from each tab.  This is for minimizing the GUI and to update the menu.  I don't know how to do this.

I tried to connect with `this->parent->parent` from the ManageSession and `ui_manag->session_ui->minimizeButton` from MainWindow.  I have a little knot in my head and I am asking for help.  Or should I re-think my design?  I´m using only QtCreator 2.6.1 with Qt 4.8.4.

[Screenshots of the GUI-Elements](http://firewall.ztweb.de/StackOverflow-Screenshots.jpg)

This is the mainwindows.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
 setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::applicationName());
 QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
 QTabWidget *ui_manag = new ManageTab;
 QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
 mainLayout->addWidget(ui_manag);
 mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
 setCentralWidget(ui_manag);
 ui_manag->setCurrentIndex(0);
 //Here comming Code to setup a TrayIcon, the Database and the Menus
}
```

The tab is completely generated by the designer:

```
ManageTab::ManageTab(QWidget *parent) :
QTabWidget(parent),
tab_ui(new Ui::ManageTab)
{
 tab_ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

For each setting I use the same GUI with multiple inheritance:

```
ManageSession::ManageSession(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
session_ui(new Ui::ManageWidget)
{
 session_ui->setupUi(this);
 session_ui->manageLabel->setText(tr("Manage Session"));

 connect(session_ui->addButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addButton_clicked()));
 connect(session_ui->editButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(editButton_clicked()));
 connect(session_ui->deleteButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteButton_clicked()));
}
//Here follows the Functions for manipulating the TableView
// and emmiting a Signal to Update the Menu
```

Comment: Could it be that inheriting from ui without specificating access is defaulting to private? So ui_manag->session_ui->minimizeButton wont work because minimizeButton is private.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the access. I´m a step forward: I can now connect from the Managetab to the Button [connect(tab_ui->manageSessionTab->session_ui->minimizeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(hideMainWindowInManageTab()));]. But I cant connect from MainWindow to the TabWidget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's remake it in an answer (so you can accept it, hehe. j/k, to long for a comment):

First. As i said in comment:

You are inheriting without specifying access. So it defaults to private. That's why

```
ui_manag->session_ui->minimizeButton
```

wont allow you to access the button.

Second. 
parent is a method, so It's: this->parent()->parent() or just parent()->parent() ;)
Again, it probably needs to inherit public. Not sure, tho.
That should work then.

Comment: My second problem was to include the "ui_managetab.h" in the "managetab.h". I only did it in the "managetab.cpp"...

Comment: Now this is running very good: "connect(ui_manag->tab_ui->manageSessionTab->session_ui->minimizeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(hide()));"

Comment: So in two or three weeks, I´ll release the new Version of my Firewall-Program on http://firewall.ztweb.de